# Remove the newline and unwanted characters at the end of each line

Tags: python-3.x

I want to remove the newline and new character from the list 
Here is my code :
zenlines=zenlines.strip('\n')
 But it throws me an error :list object has not attribute 'strip'

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57765659/why-the-output-is-not-getting-striped-of-the

Comment: Python is strongly typed. When you get an error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'` that usually means you mixed your obj types up. `.strip` is a string method only.

Answer (score 1):

it's giving an error because this is a list not a string. As suggested by another user use list comprehension,

```
z1 = [s.strip("\n") for s in zenlines]
```

this remove the \n from the start, now to remove unwanted spaces, add another statement

```
z = [s.strip(" ") for s in z1]
return z
```

Answer (score 0):

if zenlines is a list,

```
zenlines =["a  ", "b.."] 
z = [s.strip("\n") for s in zenlines]
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use newline as well as tab or space char to remove according to your scenario
try below scenario will get solve your issue.

```
zlines = [ line.strip('\n') for line in zlines ]
zlines = [ line.strip('   ') for line in lines ]
return zlines
```

Answer (score 0):

Add implementation step here

```
z1 = [s.strip("\n") for s in zenlines]
z2 = [ line.strip('   ') for line in z1 ]
    
return z2  # this will pass your test case
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
#!/bin/python3

import sys
import os
import io


# Complete the function below.

def main():
    zenPython = '''
    The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters
    
    Beautiful is better than ugly.
    Explicit is better than implicit.
    Simple is better than complex.
    Complex is better than complicated.
    Flat is better than nested.
    Sparse is better than dense.
    Readability counts.
    Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
    Although practicality beats purity.
    Errors should never pass silently.
    Unless explicitly silenced.
    In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
    There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
    Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
    Now is better than never.
    Although never is often better than *right* now.
    If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
    If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
    Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
    '''
    
    fp = io.StringIO(zenPython)
    
    zenlines = fp.readlines()
    
    z = [s.strip(" \n") for s in zenlines]
    return z
'''For testing the code, no input is to be provided'''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    res = main();
    f.write(str(res) + "\n")


    f.close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit your answer to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).